# Applying text stroke and text shadow in CSS?

Tags: html, css, shadow, effects, stroke

I'm having a bit of difficulty with CSS at the moment. I'm trying to apply both text stroke and a shadow, however I'd like to be able to change the opacity of both the stroke and shadow. I've tried however either the text shadow applies and the stroke doesn't or the stroke applies and the shadow doesn't. Any pointers? I can provide the code I was trying to use if need be.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please provide your code and for changing the opacity of the color you can use rgba color code

Comment: http://thenewcode.com/436/Outlined-Text-with-text-stroke-and-text-shadow -  check out this

Comment: ...and this might help too! https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is other way to make your text strike using `text-decoration:line-through` and apply that at your css.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/su2vf29e/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo `:after` to create strike through effect and play with its opacity to achive what you want.

Check this JS Fiddle I have created. You can change the values in the CSS part to achive what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/_vijaydev/xvse9p1o/

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I'm used to Photoshop. I meant a text stroke as in a text outline, not a strikethrough. Sorry, haha.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you can use Jinu's link and achieve the effect.

Comment: vijay example not bad also :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works for IE:

```
text-shadow: 
    2px 2px 10px color, 
    0px 2px 10px color,
    2px 0px 10px color,
    2px -2px 10px color,
    0px -2px 10px color,
    -2px 0px 10px color,
    -2px 2px 10px color,
    -2px -2px 10px color;
```

and '-webkit-text-stroke:2px color;' & a 'text-shadow:' rule for FF/Chrome.
Obviously you can change the `px` to what you want.